# Sort Django QuerySet by the combination of string fields from a M2M relationship

Tags: django, annotations, many-to-many, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models connected with a many-to-many relationship.

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bars, through='FooBars')

class FooBars(models.Model):
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=true)
   foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In a QuerySet of `Foo`, I want the related `Bars` ordered by `date` so that I can then sort `Foo` models on the combined string of the date-ordered names in `bars`.

For example:

`FooBars`:

| foo | bar | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | alpha | 01-01-2020 |
| a | beta | 01-03-2020 |
| a | gamma | 01-02-2020 |
| b | alpha | 01-01-2020 |
| b | beta | 01-02-2020 |
| b | gamma | 01-03-2020 |

QuerySet sorted on the combined string of `Foo.bars`:

| Foo | bars |
| --- | --- |
| b | alpha, beta, gamma |
| a | alpha, gamma, beta |

I've tried annotations with some combinations of `Subquery`, `F()` yet can't get the annotation to evaluate and appear on the Queryset.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: MySQL, I'm trying https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat but I still can't get it to work

Comment: I don't know if this function can follow the table join to get the `name` or if it is limited to the current columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can do the following:

```
from django.contrib.models.functions import StringAgg
from django.db.models import F, Q

res_val = Foo.objects.annotate(ordered_vals=StringAgg('bars__foobars__bar__name', ',', ordering='bars__foobars__date', filter=Q(bars__foobars__foo__name=F('name')))).values('name', 'ordered_vals')
```

[StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) documentation reference

Comment: Unfortunately using MySQL. I'm looking into https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat but so far can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

get the data

```
Foo.objects.all().values('name', 'foobars__bar__name', 'foobars__date').order_by('name','foobars__bar__name', 'foobars__date')
```

In the template you could use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup